# This is right grammar? not easy to understand this

Tags: grammar

I am wondering how I understand this below sentence.

"A low level event is the discovery of a weakness or a deficiency that could cause an undesirable effect but has not."

I didn't understand the end part of this sentence.
"but has not"

I think some words have hidden due to rewriting.
So I tried to make them revival.
is it right?

**"A low level event is the discovery of a weakness or a deficiency that could cause an undesirable effect but (the discovery of a weakness or a deficiency)has not (an undesirable effect)."

Please give me your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the sentence means is that a low level event is the discovery of a weakness or deficiency that could potentially be a problem, even if nothing's happened yet.

The fact that something could go wrong is enough to classify it as a low-level event.

Presumably if something has gone wrong already it's classified as a medium or high level event instead.

Alternate version:

> A low level event is the discovery of a weakness or deficiency that could cause an undesirable effect, but has yet to do so.

The original sentence does seem to be grammatically correct, even if it is a little unclear

Comment: very clear! thank you. when I read your comments, I 100% understood. I dont' understand why it was written like that...
"but has not" is frequently used in sentences? what is this grammar method?

Comment: It is grammatically correct, just can look strange if you're unfamiliar with the wording